# CSS pixel ratio in css media query

Tags: html, css, pixel-ratio

I am developing a website and in it I am using media queries. My Example Query is shown below

```css
only screen and (min-resolution:161dpi) and (max-resolution:192dpi),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.67)
(-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:2)
```

But when I ran it on blackberry, it didn't pick the respective css style and when I changed the `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` from `1.67` to `1`, it ran fine.

So my question is that what's the proper way to calculate the pixel ratio that will work fine with resolution also?

Comment: use pixels http://developer.blackberry.com/design/bb10/screen_sizes.html